# Zooming in stops coloring of the div

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand how stackoverflow created the black bar at the top so that no matter how much I zoom in it fills up the page when I scroll to the right.  Here is a test, zoom at about 200% and then scroll all the way to the right, the black bar stays without problems.

Go to vvv-gaming.com and zoom the same way then scroll to the right, you will notice that the red navigation bar stops.  What I can't figure out what is different on stackoverflow that makes it behave in such fashion.

I've gone and copied the html and css from stackoverflow and their code still behaves the way mine does.  Here it is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .topbar {
            width:100%;
            height:45px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.86);
            line-height: 1;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            color: white;
        }
        .topbar-wrapper{
            width: 980px;
            margin:0 auto;
            height: 34px;
            text-align: left;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: baseline;
            display: block;
        }
        .network-items{
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="topbar-wrapper">
            <div class="network-items">
                Some random text here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Go ahead and zoom that page in and then scroll to the right, you will notice that the black bar stops filling in, how do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the inner div (One where you set the width of the bar) is not being coloured.  What was happening, the color was coming from the root div and when the root div is smaller than the nav by zooming in, the color is no longer drawn.  Solution is to color the inner div as well as the top div.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .topbar {
            width:100%;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.86);
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            color: white;
        }
        .topbar-wrapper{
            width: 980px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.86);
            margin:0 auto;
            text-align: left;
            position: relative;
            display: block;
        }
        .network-items{
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="topbar-wrapper">
            <div class="network-items">
                Some random text here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create it. All you will need is this CSS:

```
.header {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color: Black;
}
```

and create the following html:

```
<div class="header"> <div>
```

See this here->http://jsfiddle.net/jZXCc/2/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Your solution brings the box left.  I need the content to stay centered and not shrink as the browser is resized.  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

It is a css trick. The width is set to 100%.

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/yourlogo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <p>Other content for your header</p>
    </div>
</div>

#header {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

.wrap {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    /*replace 900px with your width*/
    width:900px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this tonight and let you know how it went.

Comment: I tried it, it behaves exactly like my code, when you zoom in and scroll to the right the background color stops.

Answer (score 0):

It has width set to 100%, which I would assume is the difference.

If you're using Chrome (or something else with the same setup) you can just right-click and go "Inspect Element" in the future to see all the formatting applied to a div or other element on a page. It can get complicated sometime, but that will answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: Yeah I have done that, and I have also tried setting 100% width however it never made any difference.  I have also been inspecting the elements however I can't figure out the differences